# Selecting only one result row on an OR condition

Tags: sql

I have two tables, `table1` and `table2`.

The data in table1 could be something like:

```
Col1     col2
----     ----
NULL     NULL 
ABCD     NULL
NULL     DEFG
ABCD     DEFG
```

Now there is another table that contains the same two columns and contain all combinations of any of these data, like `(null, null)` or `(null, defg)` etc.

I need to write a query that picks up the matching row.

Note: priority should be given to `column1` during matching.

Comment: "Note priority should be given to column1 during matching" Can you explain this statement in more detail, perhaps with some examples of what you mean?

Comment: please post the SQL you have tried - and possibly a listing of the results you expect.

Comment: suppose table2 contains something like (abcd, pqrs) then second row i.e. (abcd,null) should be picked. But if you have something like (zxcv, defg) then third row i.e (null,defg) should be picked. Lastly if there is something like (lkjh,mnbv) then first row i.e (null,null) should be picked. Hope i have made myself clear now

Comment: please, put an example showing the two tables and the desired output

Comment: @LuisSiquot please my comment above

Answer (score 1):

I think you need three joins for this.  You don't specify what you want to do, so the following query just specifies the match type:

```
select table1.*,
       (case when fullmatch.col1 is not null and fullmatch.col2 is not null
             then 'FullMatch'
             when halfmatch1.col1 is not null
             then 'HalfMatch1'
             when halfmatch2.col2 is not null
             then 'HalfMatch2'
             else 'NoMatch'
        end) as MatchType
from table1 left outer join
     table2 fullmatch
     on table1.col1 = fullmatch.col1 and
        table1.col2 = fullmatch.col2 left outer join
     table2 halfmatch1
     on table1.col1 = halfmatch.col1 and
        halfmatch.col1 is null left outer join
     table2 halfmatch2
     on table1.col2 = halfmatch.col2 and
        halfmatch.col2 is null
```

Comment: I dont have a table -  table3 with these data. Only two tables table1 and table2 are present for me.

Comment: do you have only two tables with four records on each one??  please be clear

Comment: @RachitAgrawal . . . that was a typo.  It should have been Table2.  I changed it.

Comment: @LuisSiquot : table1 will have 4 records and table2 will have one or more record at a time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : whats t1.* ? Also when match happens i need to pick up the matched row from table1.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for the edit ..i think there is still problem with query : "halfmatch" is still unresolved .

Comment: You need to use the case statement to choose the field you want.  You need to determine whether it comes from fullmatch, halfmatch1, or halfmatch2.  The only columns mentioned in your query are the matching columns in the original table; it is redundant to add those in after an equijoin.

Comment: +1, I believe table names are reversed compared to original question. Other possible improvements - 1) Only need to test one fullmatch column in case statement. 2) Might want to consider classifying HalfMatch1 as fullmatch if col2 is null in both tables. Similar scenario for HalfMatch2. 3) Might consider a fourth join for NoMatch case, but only if the lookup table has a 3rd column of interest.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This query simply return all the rows of table1, what i require is only matching row of table1.